# Connect Airflow docker to RDS using AWS SSM Parameter Store Secrets Backend

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, airflow, amazon-rds, amazon-systems-manager

I have an `airflow` running on a `docker` machine.
Now it is working fine but I am interested in use `AWS Systems manager` as a provider of the user and password for the RDS database (`postgresql`).

I saw about `AWS SSM Parameter Store Secrets Backend`, so I set up the `airflow.cfg` with:

```
[secrets]
backend = airflow.contrib.secrets.aws_systems_manager.SystemsManagerParameterStoreBackend
backend_kwargs ={"rds_user": "/pro/database/airflow/user", "rds_password": "/pro/database/airflow/password", "profile_name":"myrole"}
```

The `profile_name` variable defines the AWS role where the parameters exists.

I also have an `entrypoint.sh` script which uses:

```
if [ -z "$AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN" ]; then
    # Default values corresponding to the default compose files
    : "${POSTGRES_HOST:="hostname"}"
    : "${POSTGRES_PORT:="5432"}"
    : "${POSTGRES_USER:=AIRFLOW__SECRETS__BACKEND_KWARGS['rds_user']}"
    : "${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:="mypassword"}"
    : "${POSTGRES_DB:="postgres"}"
    : "${POSTGRES_EXTRAS:-""}"
```

As you can see I am using `AIRFLOW__SECRETS__BACKEND_KWARGS['rds_user']` to read from the environ variable defined in the `cfg` file but it is not working. If I enter to the docker with Bash and echo variables I dont have any variable such as `AIRFLOW__XXXXXX`.

I am trying to follow `airflow docs` about it, but it doesnt explain at all how you should work with it.